# NServiceBus Distributor Worker creates a new worker queue

Tags: nservicebus-distributor, nservicebus4

I was playing with Distributor/Worker but while i was restarting the application it was creating a new Worker queue everytime with a unique id.

any clue?? and what is best place to understand more about distributor/worker and their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the endpoint, you'll see a warning logged, which explains the reason.

```
2013-08-26 18:56:48,473 [1] WARN  NServiceBus.ConfigureDistributor [(null)] <(nu
ll)> - 'MasterNodeConfig.Node' points to a local host name: [localhost]. Worker
input address name is [Orders.Handler.810aa1ea-7eb4-47b3-b639-724c4498a999@SELEN
E]. It is randomly and uniquely generated to allow multiple workers working from
the same machine as the Distributor.
```

Here's some documentation on the distributors and the explanation of the Scale out sample as well.

http://particular.net/articles/load-balancing-with-the-distributor

http://particular.net/articles/scale-out-sample.

Check out the Hands on Lab (Intermediate lab), which will walk you through the Scale out lab as well. The Scale out lab will show you how to deploy your workers to different machines by keeping the code same and just changing config. 
http://particular.net/HandsOnLabs

Hope this helps.